# Counting the frequency of certain entries in a list of JSON objects

Tags: javascript, data-visualization

I have a list of JSON objects that looks like this:

```
[{
  url: '/home',
  ...
}, {
  url: '/analytics',
  ...
}]
```

I'm using the following function to count the frequencies of the URLs in order to pass it to a c3.js chart.

```
var getSectionFrequencyData = function(data) {
  var frequencies = {};
  data.map(function(entry) {
    var matches = /[a-z]+/g.exec(entry.url);
    var url = 'home';
    if (matches) {
      url = matches[0];
    }
    frequencies[url] = frequencies[url] ? frequencies[url] + 1 : 1;
  });
  var items = Object.keys(frequencies).map(function(section) {
    return [section, frequencies[section]];
  }).sort(function(a, b) {
    return b[1] - a[1];
  }).slice(0, 10);
  return [
    ['sections'].concat(items.map(item => item[0])),
    ['frequency'].concat(items.map(item => item[1]))
  ];
};
```

This code works, but the frequency counting, sorting, and grouping seems extremely overengineered and clunky. Best practices for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach in your code is straightforward and hence easy to understand.

Nits:

- use more of ES2015+ if you use some parts of it anyway - for example `Map` is handy here;
- don't mix `function` and `=>` notations - unless the former is absolutely required;
- don't use array `.map` if you don't need the output array - to avoid garbage collection lags;

```
const getSectionFrequencyData = data => {
  const getSection = entry => /[a-z]+|$/.exec(entry.url || '')[0];

  const frequencies = new Map();
  for (const entry of data) {
    const section = getSection(entry) || 'home';
    frequencies.set(section, (frequencies.get(section) || 0) + 1);
  }

  const sorted10 = new Map(
    [...frequencies.entries()]
      .sort((a, b) => b[1] - a[1])
      .slice(0, 10)
  );

  return [
    ['sections', ...sorted10.keys()],
    ['frequency', ...sorted10.values()],
  ];
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm super intrigued though, because it contains so many things that I haven't seen before or consider as evil hacks. Using `Map` seems very elegant for the last part. I'll accept your answer for now and leave further questions about this magic later.

Comment: The only hack I've used is `[a-z]+|$` to make exec produce at least an empty string (I thought it's quite an obvious regex). What else? `|| 0` is a norm, `...` is a ES2015 *spread* syntax.

Comment: I didn't know about that regex trick and I didn't know about the existence of `Map`. I knew about spread syntax and `|| 0`. I prefer to avoid `|| 0` because it can behave differently when not using numbers.  Using spread syntax to create a copy seemed interesting and hackish. After reading the MDN docs though, it seems like that's an intended use case for it. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: `|| 0` is okay in a fully controlled case. Otherwise even integerVar++ in a `for` loop may be called a hack.